# How to split this type of string and get particular values in PHP

Tags: php

I Have a string like this

```
{"Account":{"Currency":"SGD","CreditLimit":0.0000,"Balance":1649.5700},"Status":36,"Code":891,"Message":"Success"}-
```

I need the value of Balance.

I tried like this.

```
$string = '{"Account":{"Currency":"SGD","CreditLimit":0.0000,"Balance":1649.5700},"Status":1,"Code":1,"Message":"Success"}-';
$withCharacter = strstr($string, 'Balance":');
echo substr($withCharacter, 1);
```

Tried to use explode also but no luck.

Comment: Balance value may vary all the time

Comment: Apart from the `-` at the end, this appears to be valid JSON. So remove that from the end there, and then use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a valid JSON, why not `json_decode` and find the value:

```
$i = json_decode('{"Account":{"Currency":"SGD","CreditLimit":0.0000,"Balance":1649.5700},"Status":36,"Code":891,"Message":"Success"}');
echo $i->Account->Balance;
```